# GoLang custom package import issue

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm learning GoLang, and got into an issue.

I created the mod file with `go mod init main`

Next I created controller and Routes folder which looks something like below:

```
├── contollers
│   └── users.controller.go
├── routes
│   ├── index.go
│   └── users.routes.go
├── vendor
│   └── modules.txt
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── main.go
```

in the mod file the module looks like something like this
`module main`

Now when I'm trying to import controller into router, it's giving me import error.

I been doing below things.
Attempt - 1

```
import (
    "$GOPATH/controllers"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)
```

it's giving `invalid import path: "$GOPATH/controllers"syntax` error

Attempt - 2

```
import (
    "$GOPATH/main/controllers"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)
```

again the error is same

Attempt - 3

```
import (
    "main/controllers"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)
```

controller.go

```
package controllers;

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func HealthCheck() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func (c *gin.Context)  {
        fmt.Println("reached controller")
    }
}
```

router.go

```
package routes

import (
    "bootcamp.com/server/controllers"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func UserRouters(inComingRoutes *gin.Engine) {
    inComingRoutes.GET("/api/health", controllers.HealthCheck());
}
```

it's throwing error like this, `could not import main/controllers (no required module provides package "main/controllers")`

I been stuck with this for 3-4 hours, can anyone please suggest me how can I import that controller into my route.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use modules. GOPATH is deprecated. Read go.dev/doc/code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Modify the module path by editing `go.mod`:

```
- module main
+ module example.com/hello
```

2. Modify the import path:

```
  import (
-     "main/controllers"
+     "example.com/hello/controllers"

      "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
  )
```

3. `controller.go` (remove trailing `;`):

```
- package controllers;
+ package controllers
```

4. rename the directory `contollers` to `controllers` to match the package name (`r` is missed).
5. remove the `vendor` folder.

**Explanation**:

1. `main` has a special meaning in go. Quotes from [the golang spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Program_execution):

> A complete program is created by linking a single, unimported package called the *main package* with all the packages it imports, transitively. The main package must have package name main and declare a function main that takes no arguments and returns no value.

2. Import paths without dots are reserved for the standard library and go toolchain. See [cmd/go: document that module names without dots are reserved](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32819).

Comment: still i'm getting issue. Do I need to do any other change?

Comment: This looks like a toy demo. Do you mind pushing it to github so that we can find out what's wrong?

Comment: here's the repo link,https://github.com/SohamRoyNoel/go-bootcamper-api, Can yu please help me to understand the issue.

Comment: @Nick See the pull request: https://github.com/SohamRoyNoel/go-bootcamper-api/pull/1.  You don't need the vendor directory. And others are typos.

Answer (score -1):

use this command

```
go mod tidy
```

Modify your users.routes.go

```
package routes

import (
    "main/contollers"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func UserRouters(inComingRoutes *gin.Engine) {
    inComingRoutes.GET("/api/health", controllers.HealthCheck())
}
```